# Highcharts Network Graph (Forced Directed Graph) in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

Here I have highcharts where it doesn't show up my network graph.
I had passed the data into the RouteMap component, this data was created in RouteData.js.

In the App.js you will see I'm processing the data to form the arrangement that the highcharts needed which like:

> [ [firstIndex, secondIndex], [firstIndex, secondIndex],  ... ]

and this is the code:

```
const mapStation = () => {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < routeData.length; i++) {
      const route = routeData[i].station;
      for (let j = 0; j < route.length; j++) {
        const station = route[j];
        const nextStation = route[j + 1];
        if (nextStation)
          arr.push([station.stationName, nextStation.stationName]);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  };
```

I actually wish to use .map() When I wrote this code. But I got a lot of errors when I used that. Any method so I can shorten the code above?

Here are my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-highcharts-error-kkib1?file=/src/App.js), please let me know if you are not clear about the problem.
The problem is my network graph (forced directed graph didn't show up after I passed my data into it. Data arrangements are correct according to the highcharts rules, I also had double confirmed that the data is successfully passed into it as a param. Please help me to check out any error that occurs there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `routeData` is not an array, so you can loop through it.

Try this code, without this loop:

```
  const mapStation = () => {
    let arr = [];
    const route = routeData.station;
    for (let j = 0; j < route.length; j++) {
      const station = route[j];
      const nextStation = route[j + 1];
      if (nextStation) arr.push([station.stationName, nextStation.stationName]);
    }
    console.log("test", arr);
    return arr;
  };
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-highcharts-error-forked-w20gx